# Listening to a Torah reading at night

Tags: torah-study, torah-reading, evening-night, practical-kabbalah

> Many Poskim rule based on Kabala that one is not to read verses of Mikra [Written Torah] at night.(בבאר היטב סימן רל"ח, ועיין בשער הציון סק"א)
> https://shulchanaruchharav.com/reading-tehillim-chumash-and-tanach-at-night/

Does this stringency apply to learning Mikra through listening as well? If so, may one learn by listening to a recording of a Torah reading?

Comment: The link you posted has the following section in it: "May a Baal Korei prepare the Sedra at night?
Some Poskim write it is permitted to do so."

Comment: The answer might depend on the requirement of saying bircas hatorah before learning torah by thinking without saying anything which is a machlokes between the Shulchan Aruch and the Gra https://beta.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=49623&st=&pgnum=147&hilite= . Orach Chayim 47/4

Comment: Is listening to a recording considered Torah learning to begin with?